# Use a custom button on navbar react flux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can i pass data of my page(it is a form) for when i click the button in the navbar because there are in different components.
My navbar is in my app.js like this:

```
<Scene
  key="tabhome"
  renderRightButton={<ButtonsHome/>}
  title="Publicaciones"
  icon={TabIcon}
  iconName="md-home">
```

As you can see the navbar button is the component ButtonsHome but i have in other component the page that has the form.So my question is how can i submit my form data when i click the button that is in ButtonsHome?

EDIT:

app.js

```
<Router
  navigationBarStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#262628" }}
  titleStyle={{ color: "#FFF" }}
>
  <Scene key="root" hideNavBar>
    <Scene key="login" component={Login} initial hideNavBar />

    <Scene
      key="newPost"
      component={NewPost}
      hideNavBar={false}
      renderRightButton={<ButtonsHome />} //Here is where my button submit is.
      navBarButtonColor="#fff"
    />

    <Scene
      key="tabbar"
      tabs={true}
      tabBarStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#262628" }}
      tabBarPosition={"bottom"}
      showLabel={false}
      hideNavBar
    >
      <Scene
        key="tabhome"
        renderRightButton={<ButtonsHome />}
        title="Publicaciones"
        icon={TabIcon}
        iconName="md-home"
      >
        <Scene key="home" component={Home} />
      </Scene>

      <Scene
        key="tabprofile"
        renderRightButton={<ButtonsProfile />}
        title="Perfil"
        icon={TabIcon}
        iconName="md-person"
      >
        <Scene key="profile" component={Profile} />
      </Scene>
    </Scene>
  </Scene>
</Router>;
```

And then i have my NewPost component that has a checkbox, a textInput, and a picture. And what i want is to console.log() this data i have of the inputs when i press the button inside ButtonsHome. How can i do that?

Comment: can you share the code of the parent component for this? You probably don't need to use flux for this, something like this could be handled with refs or callbacks depending on what the structure of your app is

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak I updated my answer